# How to deal with "getFloat() is not supported for current sub-class" error in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know how to deal with "getFloat() is not supported for current sub-class" error in Apache IoTDB? I created a test IoTDB in Version 1.1.1, and then copied the data folder of the official IoTDB V1.1.1 to the server where the test IoTDB is located. Then in the server of test IoTDB, I tried to load all the verified data to the test server through "tools/load-tsfile.sh -f /data/data / -h ... -p 6667 -u root -pw root --verify false" command. The above error was reported when using "select" is executed on the test server. What may be the reason for this error?